# how to fix collection add element error in Openxava 3.1

Tags: openxava

org.openxava.util.XavaException:cannot add new element in collection because an entity property is readonly..but i did not put a property readonly inside my entity class.

Answer (score 0):

IT WAS A TYPE MISTMATCH PROBLEM. WHEN I LOOKED CLOSELY TO THE CODE AND PUT THE CORRECT TYPE FOR THE ENTITY PROPERTY...IT WORKS!!! IM ABLE TO ADD ELEMENT TO THE COLLECTION.